# Understanding new architectures

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, hardware

So I'm one of those guys who, although being a young, new-generation programer, really enjoys low level development and using assembly and C. I find it cool how some people can hack game consoles to run homebrew, or port Linux to a graphing calculator, etc.

What information is needed to understand a particular architecture? For example, take the TI-89 calculator which uses the Motorola 68k. There are tons of documents on how to code for the 68k in general, but what documentation is needed to code for a specific device? Would documentation from the product manufacturer on how the CPU is wired be required? For example, on a game console, how would someone know which memory locations to write to in order to show something on the screen?

I'm not asking for documentation on TI-89 programming, game homebrew programming, etc. I know those exist. Rather, I am curious how the writers of those guides know that information.

Thanks.

Comment: Which guides, the actual manuals? They're created internally, so the question "how do they know" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @harold I'm talking about people who don't work for the company. Now thinking about it, I guess most homebrew hackers heavily rely on reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on a game console, how would someone know which memory locations to write to in order to show something on the screen?

You generally have to find technical information about the target system. What the memory map looks like, what kind of graphics chip the system uses and how you communicate with it, what kind of format(s) the graphics chip expects the graphics data to be in, and so forth.

In some cases, such information has been written down by enthusiasts (emulator developers and such) over the course of several years. For example, the [NES](http://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/Nesdev_Wiki), the [Gameboy Advance](http://problemkaputt.de/gbatek.htm) and the Nintendo DS are all pretty well documented. But there are times when only incomplete documentation can be found through public sources and you have to resort to deducing the information by experimenting with the system, or by trying to locate proprietary SDK:s to analyze (I'm not recommending such activities).

Answer (score 0):

Generally a manufacturer of a given chipset will release documentation.  You will need to learn some sort of assembly language (and compiler) that accompanies the chipset.

Intel Example:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Comment: Looking at my post, I probably wasn't clear enough. I know there are manuals for the chips themselves, but I am talking about specific applications of those chips. For example, we have the Intel manuals, but along with that, the old BIOS standard makes it easy for homebrew developers to make their small OS run on a normal PC. I guess reverse engineering is required on non-standard devices.

Comment: @QAH, 99% of the information required to build an OS is in these manuals. Of course no one just reads them, there are years of prior-art knowledge accumulated.